# What are good examples of polar sets in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ non-empty.
Its polar set $C^\circ$ is defiend as
$$C^\circ\equiv \{y\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid \forall x\in C, \,\,\langle y,x\rangle  \le 1 \},$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the Euclidean inner product.

I cannot think of an example of a set and its polar set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. What is a good example of a set and its polar set?

Comment: The polar set of the unit ball is the unit ball.

Comment: $C=\mathbb{R}^2$ and the empty set. $C=\{c\}$ and a half space.

Answer (score 9):

A few examples include:

1. The polar set of a singleton $\{x\}$ is a halfspace with support hyperplane orthogonal to $x$. If $\|x\|=1$ then the halfspace touches $x$, otherwise its below $x$ iff $\|x\|>1$:

$\hspace{40pt}$[image]

2. [The polar set of a unit disk is the disk itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1983769/173147).
3. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/630016/173147) for the polar set of $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: x^2+y^4\le1\}$.
4. Consider the polytope with the four vertices $(\pm 1,\pm1)$ (a square centred at the origin). Then its polar set is a rotated square with vertices $(0,\pm1),(\pm1,0)$:
   $\hspace{40pt}$[image]
5. You can find more examples in these lecture notes by Jonathan Kelner ([Link to pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-409-topics-in-theoretical-computer-science-an-algorithmists-toolkit-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_409F09_scribe11.pdf)).

If you have access to Mathematica, I made a simple snippet to explore how the polar sets of finite numbers of points look like. Just click anywhere to add points and see the corresponding polar set:

$\hspace{40pt}$[image]

Here's the code to generate this visualisation:

```
DynamicModule[{pts={{1,1}}},
    EventHandler[
        Dynamic@Show[
            Graphics[{
                PointSize@0.04,Dynamic@Point@pts,
                Circle[]
            },
                Axes->True,AxesOrigin->{0,0},Frame->False,PlotRange->ConstantArray[{-2,2},2],
                GridLines->Automatic,AxesStyle->Directive[Large,Black]
            ],
            RegionPlot[
                And@@(Dot[#,{x,y}]<=1&/@pts),
                {x,-4,4},{y,-4,4},PlotPoints->50
            ]
        ],
        {"MouseClicked":>(AppendTo[pts,MousePosition["Graphics"]])}
    ]
]
```

---

*See source of this answer for the MMA code used to generate the figures.*

Answer (score 3):

The basic example given by LinAlg in the comments is the key to understanding polar sets in general: when $C=\{c\}$ is just a point, then
$$
C^\circ = \{\, y\in\mathbb R^n \,|\, \langle y, c\rangle \le 1\,\} =: H_c
$$
is a half-space with the boundary hyperplanes outward normal direction being the direction of $c$ and distance from the origin given by $1/\|c\|$.

Using this, we can express polar sets in the following way for arbitrary $C\subseteq \mathbb R^n$:
$$
C^\circ = \{ \,y\in \mathbb R^n \,|\, \forall c\in C\colon y\in H_c\,\} = \bigcap_{c\in C} H_c.
$$
Hence, the polar set is an intersection of all the half-spaces $H_c$ where $c$ ranges over the points in $C$.